# Syntax error file of Icarus Verilog compiler

Tags: compiler-construction, iverilog

Does anyone know which file is the one which has the grammar in the Icarus Verilog compiler and also which one has the syntax error handing and printing?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that the grammar is the bison file `https://github.com/steveicarus/iverilog/blob/master/vvp/parse.y` (with the lexer in `https://github.com/steveicarus/iverilog/blob/master/vvp/lexor.lex`). You could start looking for error message handling in `https://github.com/steveicarus/iverilog/blob/master/vvp/compile.cc`.

Those are just guesses based on a couple of minutes looking at the repository. Good luck.